# What properties do the matrix $A^HA$ have?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$, written in the form of column vectors, is

$\mathbf{A}=(\mathbf{a}_1, \mathbf{a}_2,...\mathbf{a}_P)$

where $\mathbf{a}_k$ is an $M\times 1$ complex column vector that is given by

$\mathbf{a}_k = (1,e^{j\tau_k},e^{j2\tau_k},\cdots,e^{j(M-1)\tau_k})$,

$j＝\sqrt{-1}$ and all real constants $\tau_k$, $k=1,2,\cdots,P$, are unequal.

Assume $M>P$, then what properties, such as positive definiteness, eigenvalue decomposition, matrix rank etc, do the matrix $\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{A}$ have? And how to prove these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $A^HA$ is positive-semidefinite, which is true even without extra assumptions on $A$. It's Hermitian, since
$$(A^HA)^H = A^H(A^H)^H = A^H A.$$
It's positive-semidefinite because, for any vector $v \in \Bbb{C}^P$,
$$v^H(A^HA)v = (Av)^H(Av) = \|Av\|_2^2 \ge 0.$$
In order for it to be positive-definite, whenever $v \neq 0$, we need $\|Av\|_2 > 0$. This happens if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

When are the columns linearly independent? Note that a column of $A$ takes the form:
$$(1, \omega_k, \omega_k^2, \ldots, \omega_k^{M-1}),$$
where $\omega_k = e^{j\tau_k}$. This makes $A$ the transpose of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), whose rows are linearly independent provided they are distinct, and do not outnumber the columns. So, your matrix will be positive-definite if and only if the $\omega_k$ numbers are pairwise distinct (proving this is usually done by extending the Vandermonde matrix to be square, and [computing the determinant](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-vandermonde-determinant-a-novel-proof-851d107bd728?gi=983dd3534b00), which elegantly establishes the above claim).

Of course, you assume the $\tau_k$ numbers are pairwise distinct, but this is not quite sufficient, as the complex exponential is not injective. In fact, the complex exponential has a period of $2\pi$. So, your matrix will be positive-definite if and only if $\tau_k - \tau_l$ is only an integer multiple of $2\pi$ if $k = l$.

As for rank, the rank of $A$ and the rank of $A^HA$ agree (once again, without further assumption on $A$). This can most easily be seen by the rank-nullity theorem. The nullspace of $A^HA$ actually matches the nullspace of $A$, since
$$Av = 0 \implies A^HAv = 0 \implies v^HA^HAv = 0 \implies \|Av\|^2_2 = 0 \implies Av = 0,$$
so $Av = 0 \iff A^HAv = 0$. That is, the nullspaces agree. Since both matrices have $P$ columns, the ranks also agree.

The rank of $A$ will just be, once again, the number of distinct columns, due to the Vandermonde result. Thus, the rank of $A^H A$ will be the number of distinct $\omega_k$s. Equivalently, it will be the number of equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff (x - y)/(2\pi) \in \Bbb{Z}$ when applied to $\{\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_P\}$.

As for eigenvalues/eigenvectors, I greatly doubt that there will be a "nice" formulation for eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Obviously, if columns repeat, then we will get some $0$ eigenvalues. If $\omega_k = \omega_l$ for some $k \neq l$, then to get an eigenvector, we simply place a $1$ in the $k$th position, and $-1$ in the $l$th position, and $0$s elsewhere. For non-zero eigenvalues/eigenvectors, I don't think we'll get anything neat.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation